# AttributeError: module 'ImageFilter' has no attribute 'BoxBlur'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
import ImageFilter


def blur_im(path:str, output: str = "output.jpg"):
    OriImage = Image.open(path)
    OriImage.show()


    boxImage = OriImage.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(5))
    boxImage.show()


    boxImage.save(output)

    return 0
```

Error while calling the function.
Pls help , why there is a error in calling the function and ImageFilter as an attribute BoxBlur.I have written it correctly ig what's the issue pls help.

Error in the following line :
boxImage = OriImage.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(5))

Error:
AttributeError: module 'ImageFilter' has no attribute 'BoxBlur'

Comment: Where is that "Image" object in line 5 coming from?

Comment: I just had a look on the source code of the ImageFilter package and there simply is no function called BoxBlur. Are you using the correct package?

Answer (score 1):

Your `import` statement doesn't seem right. You are using `Image` in the first line of your function, but where are you importing it from?
Did you mean:
`from PIL import Image, ImageFilter` in case you have installed Pillow?